# Roscore without peer to peer

Tags: ros, roscore, master

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Might be an odd question.

Is there a way for Roscore (i.e Master) to disable p2p and act as a server transmitting data back and forth instead of letting peers communicating between them directly or no ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/357856/roscore-without-peer-to-peer/) by [maxime](https://answers.ros.org/users/55264/maxime/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2020-07-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-07-24**:
Could you please describe what made you ask this question (ie: *why*)?

It could be an [xy-problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Short answer: no.

http://wiki.ros.org/Master#Master_Name_Service_Example

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2020-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-07-24**:
And the answer is "no" as this would be a complete departure from how pub-sub is implemented in ROS 1.

**Comment by [maxime](https://answers.ros.org/users/55264/maxime/) on 2020-07-27**:
I was just wondering if it could be done easily. Would have been allowing me to test something quickly and give it a go.

Basically @gvdhoorn, in the solution we are building, we have several ROS1 Node. Therefore they are all build and running as a whole using docker. Each Node is a Docker container.

We have a docker internal network. The thing IS one of the containers need to be linked to the outside world. So what I tried to do was to get that container out of the internal network and instead let him on the host network. and gave him our Master Node docker ip. It works and see the Master Node but as the Master Node gives him IPs that are within the docker internal network. So it doesn't work. Hence my question.